# Sorting directory files and getting the highest file name

Tags: c#, wpf, file, sorting

I have a directory with 40 files with names from 0 to 39 (for example),
I am trying to get the file with the largest number in its name (which means I need to get "39")
I am trying to sort the directory..
I have tried using the following topics:

[How to retrieve list of files in directory, sorted by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956672/c-sharp-how-to-retrieve-list-of-files-in-directory-sorted-by-name)

[Sorting the result of Directory.GetFiles in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294275/sorting-the-result-of-directory-getfiles-in-c-sharp)

Nothing works for me..
I tried each of the methods - using Linq and the others..
and I dunno why..

I get the following result of the sorting (check picture below):
[image]

Thanks for the help,

Din Bracha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is only logical that they would be sorted that way, you would bring in some semantics to sort it by number, namely parse all the file names to numbers, then sort the files by that.

Something like

```
files.OrderBy(path => Int32.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
```

Use `Last()` to get the file with the highest number.

Comment: Or `TryParse()` to handle anything unusual without hurling an exception.

Comment: @HABO: Possibly, if it makes sense to do the error handling on a per-file basis.

Comment: @H.B. TryParse would be faster as you can avoid having a try-catch block, and much faster if there are invalid files.

Answer (score 2):

There is a native function in windows [`StrCmpLogicalW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx) that will compare in strings numbers as numbers instead of letters. It is easy to make a comparer that calls out to that function and uses it for it's comparisons.

```
public class StrCmpLogicalComparer : Comparer<string>
{
    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }
}
```

Here is a example program that will show the diffrence between the default sort and the `StrCmpLogicalW` sort

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>()
        {
            "Example1.txt", "Example2.txt", "Example3.txt", "Example4.txt", "Example5.txt", "Example6.txt", "Example7.txt", "Example8.txt", "Example9.txt", "Example10.txt",
            "Example11.txt", "Example12.txt", "Example13.txt", "Example14.txt", "Example15.txt", "Example16.txt", "Example17.txt", "Example18.txt", "Example19.txt", "Example20.txt"
        };

        items.Sort();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        items.Sort(new StrCmpLogicalComparer());

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
Example1.txt
Example10.txt
Example11.txt
Example12.txt
Example13.txt
Example14.txt
Example15.txt
Example16.txt
Example17.txt
Example18.txt
Example19.txt
Example2.txt
Example20.txt
Example3.txt
Example4.txt
Example5.txt
Example6.txt
Example7.txt
Example8.txt
Example9.txt

Example1.txt
Example2.txt
Example3.txt
Example4.txt
Example5.txt
Example6.txt
Example7.txt
Example8.txt
Example9.txt
Example10.txt
Example11.txt
Example12.txt
Example13.txt
Example14.txt
Example15.txt
Example16.txt
Example17.txt
Example18.txt
Example19.txt
Example20.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is VB.NET to retrieve the highest numbered name.  Changing the OrderByDescending key to x.LastWriteTime gets the newest file.

```
    Dim OldName As String = String.Empty
    Dim DI As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\")
    For Each FI As IO.FileInfo In DI.GetFiles("*.*").OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Name)
        OldName = FI.FullName
        Exit For
    Next
```