# C# Sorting Directory Names using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956672/how-to-retrieve-list-of-files-in-directory-sorted-by-name) but have been unable to get it working. I'm very new to LINQ and so not entirely sure what's going on with it. Any help would be appreciated. I have directory names like:

```
directory-1
article-about-something-else
```

I want to sort these by name but have been unable thus far. They are on a network drive residing on a RedHat server. The directory listing comes in a garbled mess in a seemingly random order.

Here's some of what I've tried:

```cs
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("Z:\\2013");
var dirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => dirInfo.Name);
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
{
    string month = dir.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
    var monthDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("Z:\\2013\\" + month);
    var monthDirs = monthDirInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => monthDirInfo.CreationTime);
    foreach (DirectoryInfo monthDir in monthDirs)
    {
        string article = monthDir.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(monthDir.Name);
        sb.AppendLine("<li><a href=\"/2013/" + month + "/" + article + "\">" + TextMethods.GetTitleByUrl("2013/" + month + "/" + article) + "</a></li>");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sort of at a loss at the moment. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, too.

Comment: I'll give a try, but that hasn't worked either when I used `f => f.Name`

Comment: Two things... monthDirInfo should be exactly the same as dir so why create a new object? Also Sayse is correct you need to use d => d.Name.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ordering by the name of your root folder instead of the name of each sub-directory.

So change...

```
var dirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => dirInfo.Name);
```

to ...

```
var dirs = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name);
```

and

```
var monthDirs = monthDirInfo.GetDirectories()
    .OrderBy(d => monthDirInfo.CreationTime);
```

to ...

```
var monthDirs = monthDirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
    .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTime);
```

I have used [`EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories.aspx) because it is more efficient. [`GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories.aspx) would collect all directories first before it would begin ordering them.

Comment: Erm.. that would be d.name or n => n.Name surely?

Answer (score 3):

```
dirInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var dirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name);
```

LINQ is about creating "functions" on the fly... So you're creating a function here that takes in a variable called "d" representing the current record and returns d.Name to sort.